# Scala: Return type of copy method when implicit evidence parameter has a representation type

Tags: scala, type-parameter

Let's say I have a class with a type parameter and a method that should return a copy of the instance only if the class is parameterized with a particular trait that has a representation type. I can get that to happen pretty easily. What I can't do is put a sensible return type that method:

```
case class Foo[+A](a: A) {
  // Compiles
  def gotFooBar(implicit evidence: A <:< Bar[_]) = copy(a = a.Copy())

  // Does not compile
  def gotFooBar(implicit evidence: A <:< Bar[_]): Foo[A] = copy(a = a.Copy())
}

trait Bar[+B <: Bar[B]] {
  def Copy(): B // Return underlying type
}

case class Grill() extends Bar[Grill] {
  def Copy() = Grill()
}
```

What is the return type of that function, or perhaps more importantly, how would I set up the types so that that was the return type? Could someone also point out how the real return type could be a supertype of `Foo[A]`?

Comment: Naming functions or methods with an uppercase letter coming first is a very bad idea

Comment: I suppose for this example, I could have made `Copy` lowercase, but in general, putting an abstract `copy` method in a trait is a far worse idea, since even an abstract `copy` method prevents the case `copy` method from being emitted. I frequently put `Copy` in traits and `def Copy(universal: MyClass) = copy(universal = universal)` in my case classes. In the absence of a `case trait` keyword, I find this to be the most readable way to create a class hierarchy. Instead, we could use `setUniversal`, which doesn't work with several properties, or `traitCopy`, which betrays the abstraction.

Comment: Traits, naming conflicts - whatever are the circumstances, capitalizing function names violates the essential naming conventions of Scala. If you encounter naming conflicts, just find another name: `barCopy`, `clone`, `mamboJambo`, even `copy1` would be fine, - but never name it capitalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since you only require `Bar[_]` you get `Any` as result of calling `a.Copy`. You need a type parameter for the `gotFooBar` method:

```
case class Foo[+A](a: A) {
   def gotFooBar[B <: Bar[B]](implicit evidence: A <:< B): Foo[B] = {
      val bar = a: B
      copy(a = bar.Copy())
   }
}
```

The second question is, how to enforce that `Foo[B]` is a supertype of `Foo[A]`. You just need to add `A` as a lower bound for `B`:

```
def gotFooBar[B >: A <: Bar[B]](implicit evidence: A <:< B): Foo[B]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a follow-up answer to the answer by @0__. The situation gets a little more complicated if `A` has a Manifest associated with it:

```
case class Foo[+A : Manifest](a: A)
```

The method type parameter `B` needs a Manifest too (even if you don't use it). The usual way of adding a Manifest (`: Manifest`) won't work either because that isn't allowed when the method also has implicit parameters (the `implicit evidence` in this case). The Manifest can be put in the implicit parameter list though, like this:

```
def gotFooBar[B >: A <: Bar[B]]
  (implicit m: Manifest[B], evidence: A <:< B): Foo[B] =
  copy(a = a.Copy())
```